# Disable a form field from another component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-material

I have three angular material based radio buttons namely male,female and other. So these three exist in a component.I also have three form fields namely A,B,C in another component named page1. When I press the male radio button and go to the page1 component the form field A and B in page1 component should not be visible. When I press female or other radiobutton all three form fields in page1 component should exist. I have tried for one day but nothing worked. Pls help if u know

Note:I am doing it using angular material(mat form field and mat radio button). In stackblitz I was unable to install those so pls do it in angular material way

I have attached a sample stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-routerlink-mmn77s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Create a `gettter-setter` method or use `subjct` in your service. and use that value in different component as per the expected behavior.

Comment: Can u do that in the stackblitz link pls?

Comment: No, i told you the process try to implement that. if you saw any issue after implementation then ask a separate question. This forum is not for writing code for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use BehaviorSubject or Subject to trigger the function call

TriggerService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject";

@Injectable()
export class TriggerService {
  constructor() {}
  private _trigger = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  castTrigger = this._trigger.asObservable();

  trigger(value) {
    this._trigger.next(value);
  }
}
```

parent.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private triggerService: TriggerService) {
    document.title = "Home";
  }

  changeType(value) {
    this.triggerService.trigger(value);
  }
}
```

child.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.triggerService.castTrigger.subscribe(value => {
    this._type = value;
  });
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-routerlink-qjmgg9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Is there any simpler method?

Comment: sorry don't know any other method, if child component is mentioned in parent template then  we pass type to child as @Input